# android, how to start with adsense

Tags: android, adsense

I think I suffer from a coma, or is something fishy going on?

I'm using Adwhirl & Admob in my app. Since Admob only serve an ad every 100 request I will turn 85 before I earn my first dollar. So, I decided to add adsense in the soup.

How on earth do I do that? I can read everywhere how to set it up but it is impossible to get my hands on GoogleAdView.jar smoewhere. If I nicely sign up for an account (as told) i get redirected to admob. Thank you but i already have my admob account.

So, are adsense for mobiles put to death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will give you the Adsense SDK: [Adsense SDK](http://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/source/browse/trunk/ZombieRun/libs/GoogleAdView.jar?spec=svn202&r=202)

I am using adwhirl too and have set adsense to deliver 75% of the traffic and admob is at 25%

Comment: Thank you, I actually thought that google could make it easier to find their applications but I guess they need to read a little more on internet search

Comment: Yup. Most people like us have come to expect more from a company like Google and they just don't seem up for it.